# Hash matches with collisions

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking, hashing, checksum

I'm trying to improve certain matches that happen often, on many many dimension columns.  So my choices as I understand are:

1. Match on many columns
2. Hash the columns, store the hash, match on that.

If I use something like 'checksum' is there a known algorithm to handle the collisions?
So the match would work like:

1. Partition two tables where `checksum` hashes match.
2. If there's more than one row returned, filter the results by matching all the dim columns

Anyone tried using `checksum` to make hashes faster on a large number of columns?

I should say, I'm looking for a SQL/TSQL solution.  I can easily acheive this match with python or c#

Comment: Is this not the same as your [newer question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/261813)?

Comment: @PaulWhite.  Its a derivation.  This question is more of a specific ask about a solution to the general problem.  It doesn't seem to be getting much traction so I posted the newer questions with the broader problem.  I think they are technically different question, it just maybe the answer to this older question is "never do that."